# V2ray on top of wireguard

Tags: networking, wireguard

I've done the searches but no solution was found, from what I understood Wireguard allows to add specific ips to be handled by it, is there a way to add the whole v2ray to wireguard or even better only specific users? Meaning force v2ray to use a local sort of ip only dedicated to v2ray so I can select it in wireguard and let wireguard change the outgoing stream.

The setup is simple

v2ray clinet <-----> v2ray server <-----> wireguard <---> internet

Right now I have it working but I use 0.0.0.0 for wireguard and that's not good I don't want some stuff on the server to use wireguard but now they do, also 127.0.0.1 won't work either cause those apps will also again use wireguard too.

I would love to assign a local ip to each inbound user of v2ray separately (I have users of same port with different UUIDs) like to have one ip for each user

10.66.66.1
10.66.66.2
10.66.66.3

I don't know if that's possible I searched and found nothing, but if it's not possible for a user, I'd like to still know if it's possible for the v2ray server to use an ip for everything still like:

10.66.66.1

But if that's also not possible, I'd like to know about an alternative way of doing this which I haven't thought of, any feedback would be appreciated.